# 500 - JHtmlBehavior::mootools not found when i upgrade joomla template 2.5 to 3.0

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have a gantry template for Joomla 2.5 and I converted this template to make it Joomla 3.0 compatible.

The Joomla 2.5 to 3.0 upgrade was successful, but template does not work, why? .

I get the following error:

`500 - JHtmlBehavior::mootools not found`

Comment: did you check @lodder 's answer?

Comment: Gantry is a fairly complex framework, I would never try to upgrade such a template; did you check if they published an updated version of the template? whichever number of customization it will take shorter to reapply your customization rather than migrate the whole thing yourself

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your template, you are using:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.mootools');
```

or

```
JHtmlBehavior::mootools();
```

This has been removed as of Joomla 3 and therefore needs to be changed to:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
```

Comment: plz send complete documentation for above question.

Comment: Here: http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2 you should also contact the developer of the template

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fix the extensions the following plugin can be used (and it will provide the `JHtml::_('behavior.mootools')` API call): [J25 Legacy plugin for Joomla 3.X](http://www.pluginaria.com/j25-legacy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with denis post above. I had this same problem with upgrading from j2.5 to j3X and used j25 legacy plugin from pluginaria. Found here: http://www.pluginaria.com/j25-legacy.html and got rid of the error for me. There may be a better way.... Find and replace plugin to the change code? But this is a quick and easy way to solve this issue. Make sure to activate the plugin under plugin manager after you install.... and of course make sure you have a backup before upgrading from 2.5 to 3. You should expect their to be problems.